# which linux vers

Tags: downloads

My laptop is Toshiba satellite l350-15k. My processorIntel R Core i3, Ram is 4 Gb, OS is 64 bit, display card is AMD Radeon HD 7600M series. I'm just a beginner about Linux and I couldn't decide which Linux version, I should install to my laptop.

Could someone help me, please?

Comment: [Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS](http://ubuntu-mate.org/) will be simple and good enough choose.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you Xubuntu, last night I installed it (the 18.04 version) in an old laptop and works perfectly and fluid, your can try it before install. I installed the last version with google chrome, firestorm (to play second life), skype, and clipgrab and all this take up 15,2GB. I leave you here the link if you wanna try it:

https://xubuntu.org/

I hope it can help you!